# Typescript error with SvelteKit and Supabase data fetching (Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<unknown>')

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, supabase

I have a SvelteKit project set up which authenticates with supabase. I used [this guide](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-svelte) for that. The authentication and data fetching works fine so far. Actually, in terms of the app itself, everything works as expected. I’m just getting a nasty Typescript error which I can’t get rid of.

I’m fetching the data in this file:

```
// <!-- routes/playlists/+page.ts -->

import type { PageLoad } from './$types';
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const load: PageLoad = async ({ parent }) => {
    const { supabase, session } = await parent();
    if (!session) {
        throw redirect(303, '/');
    }

    const { data: playlist } = await supabase.from('playlist').select('*');

    return {
        user: session.user,
        playlist
    };
};
```

And the corresponding svelte file to display it:

```
<!-- routes/playlists/+page.svelte -->

<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';
    export let data: PageData;
</script>

<main>
    <div>{data.user.email}</div> <!-- This works fine! -->

    <ul>
        {#each data.playlist as pl}  <!-- Typescript complains about this -->
            <li>
                {pl.spotify_uri}  <!-- and this -->
            </li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
</main>
```

Now these are the errors I’m getting:

`'pl' is of type 'unknown'.`

And

```
Argument of type '{ created_at: string; follower_count: number; last_auto_renewal: string; last_manual_renewal: string; playlist_id: number; spotify_uri: string; user_id: string | null; }[] | null' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<unknown>'.

Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<unknown>'.
```

But, as I said, on the webpage everything is displayed just as expected & I’m getting no other errors, it just seems that Typescript isn’t happy. What’s also weird is that the data.user.email thing throws no errors at all.

The auto-generated types from supabase look like this:

```
// $lib/supabase/schema.ts

export interface Database {
  public: {
    Tables: {
      playlist: {
        Row: {
          created_at: string
          follower_count: number
          last_auto_renewal: string
          last_manual_renewal: string
          playlist_id: number
          spotify_uri: string
          user_id: string | null
        }
...
```

And they seem to get inferred correctly:

[Intellisense shows this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjjCu.png)

And this is my app.d.ts:

```
import { SupabaseClient, Session } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import { Database } from '$lib/supabase/schema';

declare global {
    namespace App {
        interface Locals {
            supabase: SupabaseClient<Database>;
            getSession(): Promise<Session | null>;
        }
        interface PageData {
            session: Session | null;
        }
        // interface Error {}
        // interface Platform {}
    }
}
```

When searching for the error I found this: https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/732 and they talk about some bug in Typescript, but I’m a total Typescript beginner so I have no idea if this is related or what’s going on there.

I expected SvelteKit/Typescript to infer the types for "data.playlist" from my schema within the #each loop as well, just like it’s doing within the script tag. Not sure why it’s giving me trouble. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the supabase API can possibly return `null` for the `data` property. Not sure if that makes sense when selecting a list of objects, though, but if the type says so, you need a guard or not-null assertion.

```js
const { data: playlist } = ...
if (playlist == null)
  throw ...; // or make it a `let` and assign an empty array? 

// or
return {
    user: session.user,
    playlist: playlist!,
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For your second solution I got an *A definite assignment assertion '!' is not permitted in this context.* error, but the first solution fixed it. What also works is wrapping the {#each} block in an {#if} block, but fixing it in the page.ts is probably preferrable. (Still no idea how I could’ve inferred that this was the problem from that cryptic error though, even without the *|null* I would’ve assumed that there’s some other mismatch between this *ArrayLike<unknown>* thing and my data.)

Comment: The type errors are sometimes, maybe even most of the time, best read bottom to top, it says `Type 'null' is not assignable ...` which usually is an indication that something unexpectedly is returning `null`, you then can work up the tree to see where exactly it's coming from. Reading the errors takes some getting used to, of course.

Comment: That’s a great tip, thank you again. I’ll try that next time.